# Dafny quantifier not instantiated helpfully when faced with test data

Tags: dafny

I am trying to create a predicate in dafny that determines if an array of characters contains any duplicates. It should ultimately test for something along the lines of: For any two elements in the array, if theor values are equal, their index must also be equal. Please ignore the case where there are less than 2 elements

```
predicate noDuplicates (a:array<char>)
requires a!= null
reads a
{
forall j,k:: (0<=j<a.Length && 0<=k<a.Length) ==> ((a[j]==a[k]) ==> (j==k))
}
```

However when i run the following test, it fails the assertion. Why is this happening?

```
var b: array<char> := new char[5];
b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4] := 't', 'e', 's', 't', 's';
assert noDuplicates(b) == false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that there is nothing in the solver graph for dafny to instantiate the quantifier with. You can get it to verify by adding extra assertions so that Dafny gets the idea to use those values to instantiate the quantifiers.

For example this:

```
method Main() {
    var b: array<char> := new char[5];
    b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4] := 't', 'e', 's', 't', 's';
    assert b[0] == 't';
    assert b[3] == 't';
    assert noDuplicates(b) == false;
}
```

Or this

```
method Main() {
    var b: array<char> := new char[5];
    b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4] := 't', 'e', 's', 't', 's';
    assert b[0] == b[3];
    assert noDuplicates(b) == false;
}
```

**Why this works**

Usually when Dafny needs to prove something involving a quantifier it has to pick values to instantiate the quantifer (due to reducing to SAT). One of the things it will typically try is a fresh arbitrary constant, but that won't get you very far here. You need it to pick the values 0 and 3 (for example). However, there are a lot of ints, so the chances of picking such values at random are low - so low that in fact it won't even try. What it does instead is to look through any facts it already knows and pick out any that match the shape of atoms in the quantified formula. In this case it is looking for things like `a[i]==a[j]`  - so by putting in the assertion involving `b[0]` and `b[3]` that prompts Dafny to eventually try the values `0` and `3` for `i` and `j`. The direct version `b[0]==b[3]` works quite directly, and the indirect version `b[0]==t && b[3]==t` will indirectly cause Dafny to put edges between `b[0]` and `b[3]` in its egraph and deduce the fact `b[0]==b[3]` which will then prompt it to try `0` and `3` to instantiate the quantifer.

I would be interested to hear of any other solutions.

**EDIT**

I thought of another solution [using the `fuel` annotation](https://dafny.codeplex.com/discussions/647697), but I don't know if it is really a *better* solution:

```
method Main() {
  var b: array<char> := new char[5];
  b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4] := 't', 'e', 's', 't', 's';
  assert {:fuel contains,3} noDuplicates(b[..]) == false;
}

predicate noDuplicates (a:seq<char>)
{
   a == [] || (!contains(a[1..], a[0]) && noDuplicates(a[1..])) 
}

predicate  contains (a:seq<char>, v:char)
{
  a != [] && (a[0] == v || contains(a[1..],v)) 
}
```

Comment: Your first solution worked perfectly. Can you please explain why this is so?

Comment: Updated. The gist is that you need to give dafny a hint about which ints to try for i and j, since there are so many possible ints.